# How to move a file from one location to another on the disk?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, performance

I want to move a specific file (for example a binary .exe) that occupies a specific low offset (physical position) on my HDD to a lower offset (external edge of my HDD). From what I know I can't do it with a simple command on Windows or Linux.

Is there an application that can do it?

Comment: Why are you asking this? I ask because although I don't know a quick answer to this question, perhaps we might be able to help with the real problem which has forced you into asking this one.

Comment: Im thinking that if I could do it with some files that open with windows-boot then I could optimize the I/O read time and consequently reduces Windows Seven boot time on a HDD.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would look into myDefrag (from http://www.mydefrag.com/) which can arrange a disk exactly how you want to via various scripts that you can write for it.

It's reasonably easy to modify the existing scripts to add in particular files near the start of the disk during a defrag, or you can make a new script that simply moves a particular file.

The default "System Disk Optimization" is actually quite good already and moves most of the files needed during boot to the start of the disk.

Comment: Thank you very much, you give me the exact answear that I was looking for. Thanks!