# what is the effect of moving files to the end of the hard disk?

Tags: hard-drive

what is the effect of moving files to the end of the disk? if it is slower, is there a way to move files that shouldn't be there back to the beginning of the disk?

I would like to know as I want to place files in the best positions I can.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/290564/how-to-move-a-file-from-one-location-to-another-on-the-disk?rq=1  End of  disk is more useful for long term storage , and leaving space for new stuff. front of disk is better for speed. Note: in system defragging many many systems files are locked.

Comment: There used to be arguments for doing this, back when disks were small and slow and uncached.  I doubt that it's worth attempting anymore, both because of the relatively small potential payback and because so many things (such as "locked" files) will frustrate your efforts.

Answer (score 5):

*Reviewed Answer to give clarification - To see original answer please see edit history*

---

Utilizing the outer edge of the disk will allow for higher read speed

This is a highly simplified image the storage segments of a HDD

[image: HDD data segments]

Now there are plenty of arguments for both there is a mix of opinion and fact surrounding them and in modern HDD's there is less of a need to worry about this however...

---

### Argument for outer edge

By placing data on the outer edge you are able to access more data with each spin of the drive. Lets say you have a 7200RPM HDD this means that every minute the HDD will spin upto 7200 times or 120 times a second. Now given it can store larger amounts of data your HDD can access larger amounts of information with each spin. This will make it benchmark much higher so if you wish to go for measured speed this is your best bet.

### Argument Inner edge

There is no real need for the outer edge when dealing with small files. if you have a file that takes up 80% of a spin in the centre of the platter it will be accessed 120 times a second. This same file might take up 20% of the data of each spin on the outer edge but it will still only be access 120 times a second because a full rotation is required every time either way.

---

Ideally (imo) what you want to look at doing is grouping data that will be accessed together so that the head of your HDD has less distance to travel. Every time data needs to be accessed it still requires the HDD to spin. However by grouping data you can reducing the distance that the head needs to travel reducing access times.

Image of HDD structure for reference

[image: HDD Construction]

---

**Note/Disclaimer:**

Information provided here is opinion based. I'm not a Hardware engineer the information has no hard evidence provided. The information I've provide has come from healthy discussion with colleagues and various other IT professionals

*Take everything with a grain of salt*

Comment: @Psycogeek These are all one directional graphs and also doesn't indicate if it's the outer edge or inner edge of the platter they are starting from. If it were a comprehensive caparison you would see one graph falling and one graph rising for each direction the read/write was performed

Comment: @Psycogeek tell me if the update gives you a better understanding of the point I was trying to express

Answer (score 5):

There is a very considerable difference in speed between the inner and outer edges of a hard disk. Most good disk reviews will measure this, for example see [here](http://www.storagereview.com/seagate_barracuda_3tb_review_1tb_platters_st3000dm001), where a 3TB disk demonstrated a difference of about 2X between the inner and outer edges. HDDs spin at a fixed speed, so the outer edge is always moving faster, and the disk head will read in more data when on the outer edge than on the inner edge.

With HDDs, the beginning of the disk is the outer edge, and will be faster than the inner edge. Usually, the operating system and filesystem will not give you a way to  position files in specific locations, though defragmenting utilities will often try to shove everything to the beginning. One technique you can use is to split your disk into multiple partitions. Put your OS and programs on the first partition, use the ones farther back for media that doesn't need to be accessed quickly.

Optical media also shows this difference in speed. Often the disc will spin faster when reading the inner edge, but there is a limit to the speed the disc can spin at (the discs literally explode at higher speeds, this is why they stopped selling 52X and 56X CD drives and dropped the speed back down to 48X), and so the disc will read more slowly from the inner edge. Unlike HDDs, the inner edge is the beginning of the disk. This was done to support the 80mm Mini CDs.

Comment: I already put games on the second partition...I guess I can't move them back now unless there's a way to rearrange them.